# Akka-stream-kafka Increasing consumers in consumer group trigger a rebalance which causes a CommitFailedException because of revoked partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, akka-stream, alpakka

I think this issue is related to [#539](https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/issues/539#issuecomment-429668423) but I don't know if it is a bug, or the user is supposed to handle it himself.

So I have a consumer group, whenever i increase the number of consumer in that group, the revoking of partition is causing the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:778)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.doCommitOffsetsAsync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:617)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsAsync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:584)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitAsync(KafkaConsumer.java:1479)
    at akka.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.akka$kafka$internal$KafkaConsumerActor$$commit(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:430)
    at akka.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:210)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.akka$actor$Timers$$super$aroundReceive(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.Timers.aroundReceive(Timers.scala:55)
    at akka.actor.Timers.aroundReceive$(Timers.scala:40)
    at akka.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerActor.aroundReceive(KafkaConsumerActor.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This does not happen when i scale down the number of consumer. I mean so far i have not observed that. I assume this is because, partition are not revoke on scaling down. The remaining consumer just get new partition.

Note that, I do group message and commit batch things.

Here is how my code look like

```
val source = Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, subscription)
      .async
      .groupBy(Int.MaxValue, computeNamedGraph)
      .groupedWithin(conf.tripleStoreSettings.batchSize, conf.tripleStoreSettings.batchWindowSec seconds)
      .map(toUpdateStatements)
      .async
      .mergeSubstreams
      .map(toHttpRequest)
      .map(p => p.data -> p)
      .via(poolClientFlow)
      .async
      .map { case (respone, payload) => Payload(respone, payload.offsets) }
      .mapConcat(handleResponse)
      .via(Committer.flow(committerDefaults.withMaxBatch(conf.tripleStoreSettings.batchSize)))

    val (killSwitch, streamResults) = source
      .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
      .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.both)
      .run()

    streamResults.onComplete {
      case Success(_) =>
        logger.info("Stream finished")
        system.terminate()
      case Failure(e) =>
        logger.error("Stream failed:", e)
        system.terminate()
    }
```

My decider just does the following:

```
 private val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
    e => {
      logger.error(s"Stream failed. ${e.getMessage} ${e.getStackTrace.map(_.toString).mkString("\n")}", e)
      Supervision.Stop
    }
  }
```

So I understand based on my reading of  #539 that i have a number of inflight messages to commit back and I can't because of the revokation. That is, there is  some rebalance that involve revokation that happen when the number of consumer is scaled up.

My service is at-least once, so i don't mind if another consumer reprocess those message. we don't have an at-most-one deliver constraint.

My question would be until the library handle those situation natively, how can i go about committing them anyway whenever revoke occurs or better yet, just discard them, so the consumer who get assigned the partition they belong too, will reprocess them.

Any suggestion ? I check the BalanceListener but i am not sure how to go about using it for this situation.

*Note My timeout configs*

```
val subscription = Subscriptions.topicPattern(conf.kafkaConsumer.sourceTopic)
    val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(system, new StringDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
      .withBootstrapServers(conf.kafkaBroker.bootstrapServers)
      .withGroupId(conf.kafkaConsumer.groupId)
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, conf.kafkaConsumer.offsetReset)
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "5000000")
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "100000")
```